# Can't echo to /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, serial

I have an arduino connected to /dev/ttyUSB0.  I try to send '1' to it using

echo 1 > /dev/ttyUSB0

but nothing seems to happen. However, if I do this beforehand:

tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0 &

and try the echo command again, it works.  Why is this?

Comment: What is it you were expecting to happen?

Comment: The arduino reads the serial port and if I send it a 1 it switches some remote control sockets on. If I send it a 2 it switches them off. It doesn't send any kind of reply back on the serial connection - I removed that in case it was causing the problem.

Comment: Note that `echo` by default adds a newline which I presume the dev interface passes straight through, so that will actually be two bytes, `1\n`, although that doesn't make much difference to what you're describing.  You can use `echo -n` to suppress that.

Comment: The arduino code reads the first byte and then discards the remainder.  What I don't understand is why it works when I have another process tail the port

Comment: I've never tried using the serial port this way. My first guess is that the TX line only goes high when it is opened by an application, and without that transmitting a few bytes probably won't work.  You could verify this with a multimeter.  I think the [hardware pulls it low](http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs) by default and there's no reason for the OS driver to change that unless the "device" is actually in use.  UART communication is about the line dropping, not rising, in pulses.  A continuously low RX (opposite the Pi's TX) would indicate no connection to the Arduino.

Comment: do the serial port settings [match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57629/129968) the arduino's ? can you try with a terminal app like `minicom` ?

Comment: If I use something like screen /dev/ttyUSB0 it works fine.  I now think my problems are down to the fact that the arduino resets itself when the serial connection is made.  This takes a second or so, and it does not have enough time to receive the results of the echo command. It seems that having the tail -f command keeps the arduino from resetting as that holds the serial port open.